# What are some good classical pieces to start learning analysis for the beginner?

Tags: theory, harmony, classical-music, analysis

I'm in Piano grade 7 Royal Conservatory of Music and I'm finding Analysis to be quite challenging. I have no problem reading the music but if I really want to be able to learn a piece well I have to learn how to analyze pieces and keep in mind or the underlying harmony. The thing is, I can't really figure out the underlying harmony because I can't do things like distinguishing between chord tones and non-chord tones and with modulations. does anyone have suggestions on books, videos, guides on harmonic analysis and some good pieces to start practicing with?

Comment: Why not ask some of your teachers for some help?

Answer (score 4):

I know how expensive textbooks are, but I genuinely think a great textbook is the best answer to your question. Probably my favorite textbook for straightforward learning outside of a class environment is the text by Aldwell and Schachter called *Harmony and Voice Leading*. However, it's probably the most difficult standard text and might be better after you've already learned some details from elsewhere. A somewhat simpler, but still great, textbook is Clendinning and Marvin's *Musician's Guide to Theory and Analysis*.

As far as some pieces that are somewhat easier to do an analysis of due to relative lack of non-chord tones and chromaticism, you might try the beginnings of Bach's first prelude from the first book of the *Well-Tempered Clavier* and Beethoven's so-called *Moonlight Sonata*, but even those will have the occasional moment that takes further study to understand.

Comment: +1 "simple" Bach keyboard material is a very good place to start - the structure and development are clear and logical.  But Beethoven, not so much.

Comment: @Stinkfoot That's why I specified the *beginning*of moonlight, not the whole thing (once the modulations start it's pretty tricky, although the chords aren't necessarily). What I was thinking is that it's a super-famous piece and the straightforward arepeggiation in the left hand is easy to parse. Admittedly, there is the one Neapolitan chord…

Comment: I understand - certainly familiarity will make things easier and the beginning is pretty straightforward. When I read the question I was going to suggest some of the beginning preludes in Well Tempered -
 they really are the best IMO - but I saw you already did. I am no expert in analysis for sure, but what I do know I started from Well Tempered preludes and they were perfect for study.

Comment: To your Bach suggestion i'd add a reference that i found indispensable while studying the classical harmony: *371 Harmonized Chorales and 69 Chorale Melodies with Figured Bass* (Ed. Albert Riemenschneider).

Answer (score 0):

As a Royal Conservatory of Music graduate, I'm sorry I need to say this, but have you ever taken Harmony lessons? Basic Harmony (2009 syllabus) and Level 9 Harmony (2016 syllabus) both teach non-chord tones.

In addition, the 2009 syllabus has a list of resources (books) you can draw upon for music theory lessons.